# Перенос куска текста из одной колонки в другую sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

В БД есть колонка с ссылками и текстом:

```html
<p><a href="/content/primer.pdf" target="_blank">Инструкция pdf</a></p>
```

Ссылки все разные, можно ли перенести как-то только этот кусок из одной колонки в другую, чтобы выбирался с

```html
<p><a href="/content/ и заканчивался </a></p>
```

?

Comment: *колонка с ссылками* Что, в одном значении может быть несколько ссылок? или строго одна?

Comment: @Akina есть колонка в БД "TEXT" колонка имеет 500 записей. В каждой записи есть по одной ссылке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то типа

```sql
UPDATE test
SET
lnk = CONCAT(@marker1,
             SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(txt, @marker1, -1), @marker2, 1),
             @marker2),
txt = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(txt, @marker1, 1),
             SUBSTRING_INDEX(txt, @marker2, -1));
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f5c15c5e0788752729a97d6cbd14ab83